# React-Native Button onPress not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to bind the function `handleClick` to my button `onPress`. But it's not working. When I refresh the page, I get the alert without clicking on the button and after I close the alert and click on the button, nothing happens.

My Code is:

```
class ActionTest extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      thename: 'somename'
    };
  }

  handleClick(){
    alert('Button clicked!');
  }

    render(){
      return(
        <View>
          <Button
           onPress={this.handleClick()}
           title="Click ME"
           color="blue"
          />
        </View> 
        );
    }
}
```

I'm also getting the warning :

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are invoking the handleclick function when the component renders you want to do `onPress={this.handleClick}` So this way it will be a callback and will only run the function when the onpress i triggered

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are calling handleClick when it renders as you have `onPress={this.handleClick()}`

try `onPress={this.handleClick}` instead, to pass it the function as a callback.

Answer (score 15):

First you define your click handler as an arrow function. In this way you don't need to bind the function anymore. Your function will be like this:

```
handleClick = () => {
    alert('Button clicked!');
}
```

Then use this function in the `<Button>` tag like this:

```
<Button
 onPress={this.handleClick}
 title="Click ME"
 color="blue"
/>
```

Answer (score 6):

When react-native detects a click event and wants to notify you, it calls the `onPress` prop as a function. so you have to give **a function** to `onPress` prop like:

```
onPress={this.handleClick}
```

this connects `onPress` to `handleClick` method. but if you want to call other methods in `handleClick` and you need "`this` object" you can pass the `handleClick` method like this:

```
onPress={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
```

Good luck

Answer (score 3):

update your code! you should pass a reference

```
<Button
       onPress={this.handleClick}
       title="Click ME"
       color="blue"
      />
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try it

```
class ActionTest extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      thename: 'somename'
    };
  }

  handleClick=()=>{
    alert('Button clicked!');
  }

    render(){
      return(
        <View>
          <Button
           onPress={this.handleClick}
           title="Click ME"
           color="blue"
          />
        </View> 
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you change and why does it solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

- 

```
You can also call the function like this: 
class ActionTest extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      thename: 'somename'
    };
  }
  handleClick(){
    alert('Button clicked!');
  }
    render(){
      return(
        <View>
          <Button
           onPress={()=>this.handleClick()}
           title="Click ME"
           color="blue"
          />
        </View> 
        );
    }
}
```

- 

Answer (score 0):

We are supposed to pass a function reference instead of calling it directly while rendering:

Try this:

```
onPress={this.handleClick}
```

Answer (score -3):

if you define your function out of scope of your class also you don't use `this` keyword with your handler function

like

```
//function moved here
const handleClick = () => {
    alert('Button clicked!');
  }

class ActionTest extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      thename: 'somename'
    };
  }
    render(){
      return(
        <View>
          <Button
           onPress={handleClick()}
           title="Click ME"
           color="blue"
          />
        </View> 
        );
    }
}
```